# setup gxt project for tomcat 7 deployment

Tags: java, gwt, tomcat, gxt

I've made .war file from war folder of my project and copied it to tomcat's ROOT directory. Then I start tomcat and get either `GWT module 'hellogxt' may need to be (re)compiled` or `404 error`. What I am doing wrong?

update
here is log of gxt compilation

```
Compiling module com.hello.gxt.HelloGXT
   Compiling 6 permutations
      Compiling permutation 0...
      Compiling permutation 1...
      Compiling permutation 2...
      Compiling permutation 3...
      Compiling permutation 4...
      Compiling permutation 5...
   Compile of permutations succeeded
Linking into D:\path\HelloGXT\war\hellogxt
```

Link succeeded
   Compilation succeeded -- 105.573s

Comment: put it inside <tomcat home>\webapps folder. Then navigate to http://localhost:8080/nameOfWar (after you've started tomcat ofcourse:) )

Comment: war is in webapps\ROOT directory. tried your method, didn't help :(

Comment: It seems that your gwt compile failed. 
Clean your project and recompile it and look if GWT compiler does the permutations in the logs.

Comment: @jtrentes see question update

Answer (score 0, accepted):

found [useful link](http://blog.elitecoderz.net/gwt-and-tomcat-create-war-using-eclipse-to-deploy-war-on-tomcat/2009/12/). Just followed steps and ... PROFIT!